# Neo4j count and order relationships to list of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph of people and items. The relationship is one to many `(a:Person)-[:has]->(b:Item)`. For an input list of items, I am trying to get a list of people that have that item, ordered by who has the most items in the list.

[image]

In the above image I would expect an output like:

```
[{"Person 1", count: 3},{"Person 2", count: 2},{"Person 3", count: 1}]
```

I tried a few variations of:

`match(a:Person)
 match(b:Item) where b.label in ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
 return a,count( (a)-[:has]->(b))`

and

`match(n:Item) return n, size((n)-->()) as count` where the counts are correct but when I try to narrow the Items to a list the count is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[:has]->(b:Item)
RETURN a, count(b) ORDER by count(b) DESC
```

Comment: I thought I tried this and got an error where b is undefined, but it seems to work. I will test a few more things and accept your answer.